# Making a custom search form on a Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

So I made a form for a custom search on my Wordpress site. Right now I made a function in my `functions.php` file that creates a short code. I then put the short code where I want to display the form. Everything works fine. My question is is this the best way to do this? Should I make it a widget instead? Are there any possible unintended consequences in doing it this way?

```
function zip_search_form() {    
    $form='<form id="zipcode" action="" method="post">
    <input class="form-control search-input" autocomplete="off" name="zipcode" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" />
    <input type="submit" /></form>'; 

    return $form;
}

add_shortcode('zip_search', 'zip_search_form');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, its fine doing it like this. 
I like to keep things clean and easy to read as a developer. Therefore having things in functions.php is nice and a common way to do so in Wordpress.

I dont think it makes any difference to have it in a widget, because the logic in the code would be more or less the same.

A small update, you can consider to use (simply made it a line shorter):

```
function zip_search_form() {
    return '<form id="zipcode" action="" method="post">
            <input class="form-control search-input" autocomplete="off" name="zipcode" 
            type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" /><input type="submit" /></form>';
}
add_shortcode('zip_search', 'zip_search_form');
```